# while loop to constantly recheck changes in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, while-loop

I have two identical dataframes `new` and `old`. The `new` dataframe will be updated randomly throughout the day. The code below checks if there are any changes.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

new = {'name': ['Sheldon', 'Penny', 'Amy', 'Bernadette', 'Raj', 'Howard'],
                'episodes': [42, 24, 31, 29, 37, 40],
                'gender': ['male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male']}
old = {'name': ['Sheldon', 'Penny', 'Amy', 'Bernadette', 'Raj', 'Howard'],
                'episodes': [12, 32, 31, 32, 37, 40],
                'gender': ['male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male']}    

df1 = pd.DataFrame(new, columns = ['name','episodes', 'gender'])    
df = pd.DataFrame(old, columns = ['name','episodes', 'gender'])

while True:
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(new, columns = ['name','episodes', 'gender'])    
    print(df[~df.episodes.eq(df1.episodes)])
    df1 = df
```

I need to write condition inside a `while` loop where `df[~df.episodes.eq(df1.episodes)]` is only printed if there is a change detected. After the new data is printed it would set both the dataframe to same values(because old data is not longer needed) and recheck for changes. The above code would print :

```
Columns: [name, episodes, gender]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [name, episodes, gender]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [name, episodes, gender]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
```

Thus one would miss if a change has actually been printed. Could you please advise a more efficient way of accomplishing this.

== Edit ==

As per the anwer by @BENY if i do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

new = {'name': ['Sheldon', 'Penny', 'Amy', 'Bernadette', 'Raj', 'Sheldon'],
                'episodes': [42, 24, 31, 29, 37, 40],
                'gender': ['male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male']}
old = {'name': ['Sheldon', 'Penny', 'Amy', 'Bernadette', 'Raj', 'Sheldon'],
                'episodes': [12, 32, 31, 32, 37, 40],
                'gender': ['male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male']}    

df1 = pd.DataFrame(new, columns = ['name','episodes', 'gender'])    
df = pd.DataFrame(old, columns = ['name','episodes', 'gender'])

while True:
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(new, columns = ['name','episodes', 'gender'])    
    out = df.merge(df1[['name','episodes']],on=['name','episodes'],how='left',indicator=True).loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only']
    print(out)
    df = df1
```

It would print this out for the entire whileloop:

```
         name  episodes  gender     _merge
0     Sheldon        12    male  left_only
1       Penny        32  female  left_only
3  Bernadette        32  female  left_only
         name  episodes  gender     _merge
0     Sheldon        12    male  left_only
1       Penny        32  female  left_only
3  Bernadette        32  female  left_only
         name  episodes  gender     _merge
0     Sheldon        12    male  left_only
1       Penny        32  female  left_only
3  Bernadette        32  female  left_only
```

Is there any way it would print it only once. Until there is another change. If i `df= df1` than it would print the as below and I would miss the change:

```
Columns: [name, episodes, gender, _merge]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [name, episodes, gender, _merge]
```

I need to get this data cleanly where the changes are detected.

Comment: I did see your earlier question, but not clear yet, have you tried compare? `df.compare(df1,keep_shape=True)` this will return values only when the columns vary, else NaN. May be that will help you. Dont try a loop when not required. Pandas and Numpy are mostky vectorized and you dont need a loop most of the time

Comment: How can i do it so that it is checking for changes all the time without a while loop. new data can change anytime

Comment: Not sure on your requirement yet but I would think of implementing a SCD type 2 maybe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2:_add_new_row based on what I gather

Comment: maybe `while True:
    if df.equals(df1) == False:` Then print out the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare the 2 dataframe and check for any changes/differences, why not use the [`DataFrame.compare()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html) function ?

Here's the sample output based on your sample data:

```
df.compare(df1)
```

**Output:**

```
    episodes      
    self other
0   12.0  42.0
1   32.0  24.0
3   32.0  29.0
```

By default, it highlight only the differences.  Here, it shows that only the column `episodes` has differences.
`self` corresponds to the values of `df` and `other` corresponds to the values `df1`

The indexes on the left, ie.  `0`, `1`, and `3` show the row indexes with differences.

If you want to show the whole original shape, you can also use the `keep_shape=` parameter, as follows:

```
df.compare(df1, keep_shape=True)
```

**Output:**

```
  name       episodes       gender      
  self other     self other   self other
0  NaN   NaN     12.0  42.0    NaN   NaN
1  NaN   NaN     32.0  24.0    NaN   NaN
2  NaN   NaN      NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
3  NaN   NaN     32.0  29.0    NaN   NaN
4  NaN   NaN      NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
5  NaN   NaN      NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
```

Only different values are shown.  `NaN` values are those without differences.

Of course, if you like, you can also choose to display all values, including equal values, as follows:

```
df.compare(df1, keep_shape=True, keep_equal=True)
```

**Output**

```
         name             episodes        gender        
         self       other     self other    self   other
0     Sheldon     Sheldon       12    42    male    male
1       Penny       Penny       32    24  female  female
2         Amy         Amy       31    31  female  female
3  Bernadette  Bernadette       32    29  female  female
4         Raj         Raj       37    37    male    male
5      Howard      Howard       40    40    male    male
```

This options allow you side by side comparison to inspect the difference.  Anyway, it is less easy to spot the differences.

I would suggest you take the default options to display only the differences first (may be write down the indexes of rows with differences) and optionally, use the other 2 options only when you want detailed inspection of the other side values (which are equal).

To use under your `while` loop, you can use:

```
while True:
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(new, columns = ['name','episodes', 'gender'])    
    out = df.compare(df1)
    print(out)
    df = df1
```

### Edit

If you want to see the `name` while maintaining to see only the differences of other columns, you can set index with `append=True`, as follows:

```
df.set_index('name', append=True).compare(df1.set_index('name', append=True))
```

**Output**

```
                 episodes      
                 self other
  name                     
0 Sheldon        12.0  42.0
1 Penny          32.0  24.0
3 Bernadette     32.0  29.0
```

This way, you can see both the `name` and the row indexes with differences.

Comment: How can i just see the changed in columns? Because the df where i am planning to run this has hundreds of entries

Comment: @Slartibartfast  With the default option of `.compare()`, it can already show multiple columns if there are more than one column with differences.   Is this what you mean by "see the changed in columns' ?

Comment: For example `2         Amy         Amy       31    31  female  female` was showing up but there are no changes to that entry. Is there anyway to suppress that? And show only where there are changes?

Comment: @Slartibartfast   From the example above, using the default option with code `df.compare(df1)`, the row index 2 without differences is not shown, right ?   So, you can just use `df.compare(df1)`

Comment: @Slartibartfast  The first `2` is the row index.  You can see from the example above that it only shows the rows `0`, `1`, `3`, without showing `2`, right ?   And even with the 2nd option using parm `key_shape=True`, it will only show `2  NaN   NaN      NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN` , right ?

Comment: Perhaps i could set the name as index that way i could get the names also?

Comment: @Slartibartfast  Right, that's a clever way to do it, if you want to show the index for all cases.  But would your name be duplicated ?

Comment: @Slartibartfast  One way to do it even for duplicate names, is to append the name as index by e.g.  `df.set_index('name', append=True).compare(df1.set_index('name', append=True))`

Comment: @Slartibartfast  See my edit above on the code and sample output.

Comment: @Slartibartfast  As I mentioned in the answer, option 3 with `keep_equal=True` will shows also equal values (including equal rows).  So probably, you show not use this option, unless you want to inspect also other column values.  With the first 2 options, row 2 won't be shown.   If your `name` column has special meaning and you want to show it always, you can use the set index method in the edit but remember to use the first option, i.e. with default settings for `.compare()`.

Answer (score 1):

Let us try with `merge`

```
out = df.merge(df1[['name','episodes']],on=['name','episodes'],how='left',indicator=True).loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only']
         name  episodes  gender     _merge
0     Sheldon        12    male  left_only
1       Penny        32  female  left_only
3  Bernadette        32  female  left_only
```